# How do I connect to mysql from Ionic mobile apps?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, ionic-framework

I try to connect my ionic app to mysql using php but it doesn't work .
xampp use port 8180 and ionic use port 8100

```
.controller('AddController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
  $scope.enregistrer=function(){
    $scope.responseMessage="pfffff";
    $http.post("http://localhost:8180/add.php",{'nom':$scope.nom,
                          'prenom':$scope.prenom,
                          'email':$scope.email,
                          'adresse':$scope.adresse,
                          'sexe':$scope.sexe,
                          'active':$scope.active}).success(function(data,status,headers,config) {  
                                        $scope.responseMessage = "Successfully Created Account";;
                                      });
 }
}]);
```

add.php :

> if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
>           header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
>           header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
>           header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
>       }
>
> ```
> // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
> if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
>
>     if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
>         header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         
>
>     if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
>         header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
>
>     exit(0);
> }
> $request=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
> $nom=mysql_real_escape_string($request->nom);
> $prenom=mysql_real_escape_string($request->prenom);
> $email=mysql_real_escape_string($request->email);
> $adresse=mysql_real_escape_string($request->adresse);
> $active=mysql_real_escape_string($request->active); 
>
> $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
> mysql_select_db("ionicbd",$con);
>
> $query="insert into user(`nom`,`prenom`,`email`,`adresse`) values($nom,$prenom,$email,$adresse)";
> $queryRes=mysql_query($query);
> if($queryRes) echo "1";
> else echo "2";
> ```

I got the response "Successfully Created Account" as output but I can't receive the data from the app

The errors that I got :

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\add.php on line 24

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\add.php on line 25

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\add.php on line 26

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\add.php on line 27
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved :
I should just add `ng-controller="AddController"` in add.html and delete the headers in my function and delete all the headers in my add.php and keep just `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

Answer (score 0):

The notice you got say that your $request variable is not an object. It must be an array.

Try:

```
$request=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$nom=mysql_real_escape_string($request['nom']);
$prenom=mysql_real_escape_string($request['prenom']);
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($request['email']);
$adresse=mysql_real_escape_string($request['adresse']);
$active=mysql_real_escape_string($request['active']);
```

Comment: i got another error , the first one s gone : "" You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',)' at line 1 ""  @Getz

Comment: Ask another question, it's not the same problem.